# Is is possible to make Span single line and end of text to finish with 3 dots?

Tags: android, textview, spannable

I'm using Drafty formatting for displaying Quoted messages
[image]

If I write long message instead of 'quoted text' (in the picture), it doesn't display as single line and with dots.

How can I display it like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi, have you find a solution to this? I am thinking about comparing TextView's width with text's measured width from TextPaint. What did you use?

Comment: Hi, no I have not found a solution, but I could use another view for quoted messages. For example, `normal_message_cell.xml`,  `quoted_message_cell.xml`, `audio_message_cell.xml` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me the ***XML*** file of the design?

for now i can assume that you have set **constraints** of your Quoted message with above title.

**->** you can **remove** the constraint and set it free to expand its width, hope it will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: There is used just one TextView for display a reply message. And also spans are setting dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In the layout definition of TextView,

```
<TextView
   ... Rest of your stuff
   android:lines="1"  // or 2 (if the name and message are part of the same view)
   android:ellipsize="end"/>
```